# What's the significance of the two rolls and the bee in "The Unbearable Lightness of Being"?

Tags: milan-kundera, the-unbearable-lightness-of-being, czech-language

Towards the end of *The Unbearable Lightness of Being* by Milan Kundera (Czech: *Nesnesitelná lehkost bytí*), Tereza has a dream about Karenin, their dog, giving birth to two rolls and a bee:

> Karenin gave birth to two rolls and a bee. He stared, amazed, at his own progeny. The rolls were utterly serene, but the bee staggered about as if drugged, then flew up and away.
> Or so it happened in Tereza's dream. She told it to Tomas the minute he woke up, and they both found a certain consolation in it. It transformed Karenin's illness into a pregnancy and the drama of giving birth into something both laughable and touching: two rolls and a bee.
> <sub>*The Unbearable Lightness of Being*, part 7: "Karenin's Smile", section 3 (translated by Michael Henry Heim, 1984)</sub>

> Just then Tereza recalled her dream: Karenin giving birth to two rolls and a bee. Suddenly the words sounded like an epitaph. She pictured a monument standing there, between the apple trees, with the inscription *Here lies Karenin. He gave birth to two rolls and a bee*.
> <sub>*The Unbearable Lightness of Being*, part 7: "Karenin's Smile", section 5 (translated by Michael Henry Heim, 1984)</sub>

Previously in the book, Tereza's dreams have been explained by the narrator, such as her dream with the women marching and being shot by Tomas.

I'm inclined to assume, then, that this dream as well has some significance. If it had just been the first mention, I would have assumed that the explanation was what was mentioned: that "certain consolation". However, with the mention later on about it sounding like an epitaph, I'm getting the impression that I'm missing some signficance here.

What's the significance of the two rolls and the bee in this dream?